# How does GradientDescentOptimizer.minimize() work?

Tags: tensorflow, training-data, gradient-descent

In regard to TensorFlow, I am confused with how `GradientDescentOptimizer.minimize()` actually works. To be more specific through the code below, how does calling `minimize(error)` modify the `m`, `b`  so that when I just call `sess.run([m, b])`, they return the modified `m`, `b`value? I think it's hard to find any connections between `minimize()` and Variables `m` and `b` like the result at the end of this following code:

```
#Actaul Data
x_data = np.linspace(0, 10, 10) + np.random.uniform(-1.5, 1.5, 10)
y_label = np.linspace(0, 10, 10) + np.random.uniform(-1.5, 1.5, 10)

#Random Variables --> These variables will be be modified by minimize()
m = tf.Variable(0.44)
b = tf.Variable(0.87)

error = 0

for x, y in zip(x_data, y_label):
    error += (y - (m*x + b)) ** 2

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
train = optimizer.minimize(error)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    training_steps = 100

    for i in range(training_steps):
        sess.run(train)

    final_slope, final_intercept = sess.run([m, b])

    print(final_slope, final_intercept) # 0.7535087, 0.83729243
```

Comment: Are you familiar with machine learning ? You use the variables `b` and `m` to compute your error, it seems logical that their value changes while you're trying to minimize your error.

Comment: Well, I am not conversant with machine learning, unfortunately. However, I am kind of wondering how does minimize() function actually know that m and b are to be fixed and fix it? What if it's not mx+b but other expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link between your optimizer and the trainable variables like *m* and *b* is this.

*Trainable variables*

You can set this parameter to *False* to exclude any variable from training. In your code by default *trainable* is True. It will pick up any other variable and try to optimize it too if *trainable* is not *False*.

```
m = tf.Variable(0.44,trainable=False)
b = tf.Variable(0.87)
```

The output in this case is

> 0.44 2.134535

*Explicitly passing var_list*

It is possible to collect all trainable variable using code.

```
variables = tf.trainable_variables()
allvariables = [var for var in variables]

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
train = optimizer.minimize(error,var_list=variables)
```

So if it's not *mx+b* but other expressions we can optimize whatever we want.

There are probably other advanced ways to control this.

```
with tf.variable_scope('discriminator'):
    c = tf.Variable(1.0)

variables = tf.trainable_variables()
allvariables = [var for var in variables if var.name.startswith("discriminator")]
```

This includes just *c*.